# Is KoGrid developing?

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, kogrid

Development of KoGrid seems not active around 5 month... Maybe someone know something about future of KoGrid? Do someone know alternatives for KoGrid(another grid with supporting of knockout) for integration with breezejs?

Comment: I think this is a valid question. Maybe you should change the question to concern the future of KoGrid and not the alternatives and breezejs stuff. The project on GitHub contains 12 pull requests and 77 issues and nothing is being looked at.

Comment: According to https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid/issues/246, it is not: "After trying to make ng-grid and kogrid have a similar base to build functionality off of, it was more of a hassle to implement some of the things we wanted to do in knockout (kogrid), so we have just been working on ng-grid. If anyone wants to take over KoGrid or fork, just post in the comments section here."